# Block case creations if the subject contains PTO

Tags: apex, trigger

Am able to block cases if subject line contains PTO using below condition.

```
if(caseToProcess.subject.containsIgnoreCase('PTO'))
     caseToProcess.addError('Out-of-office type subjects are not allowed to create new cases.');
```

But the problem is what happens if the subject line contains 'ada**pto**rs' where pto is present. It is blocking the case creation.

Also we cannot assure that customer will put only PTO or PTO: or some other for exaft PTO cases.

My idea is, find actual PTO by searching prefix and suffix of the PTO. If there are characters before and after PTO it is not actual PTO.

NOTE: like PTO we have many keywords.

Any help is appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use a Pattern to discern if there's a match:

```
Pattern ptoPattern = Pattern.compile('\\b(?i)pto\\b');
if(ptoPattern.matcher(caseToProcess.subject).find()) {
    caseToProcess.addError('Out-of-office type subjects are not allowed to create new cases.');
}
```

Where `\\b` matches a "word boundary", `(?i)` means "case insensitive", and `pto` matches PTO in any case.

As a matter of performance, you should consider "compiling" the pattern once outside of the loop. If you want to match more keywords, you can also use the OR operator:

```
Pattern ptoPattern = Pattern.compile('\\b(?i)(pto|ooo|wfh)\\b');
```

Comment: Greate thanks for the help. My debugs,
subject : adaptors  ------> not matched.

subject : pto adaptors  -----> matched

subject : pto: adaptors  -----> matched